# Remove item from FlatList in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using Flat List in react native to select Multiple images from gallery. Now i want to remove some of image before uploading it to server. I am not sure how to perform that action.

Here is my code...

```
<FlatList
          style={{ paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop: 10 }}
          data={this.state.imagesAddFile}
          keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <SelectedLayout
             ImageName = {item.name}
            />
          )}
        />
```

Here i am getting list of images properly but not sure how to delete image from list please suggest am answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using delete function like below method sharing all the code here:

Step 1: Render view in add a TouchableOpacity like below code:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteAddress(itemData.item._id)}>
                <Icon name="trash" style={{paddingLeft: 10,paddingRight:10}} size={20} color="red" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

Step 2: Add a confirmation box like below code:

```
deleteAddress(id) {
    Alert.alert(
      'Delete Address',
      'Are you sure want to delete this address ?',
      [
        {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
        {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.deleteAddressDetail(id)},
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    )
  }
```

Step 3: Call your API or anything here:

```
deleteAddressDetail(id) {
  //Delete api or anything here
  //after that call your list so updated state data will render
}
```

Your updated flatlist code:

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.addressList}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        extraData={this.state}
        renderItem={this.renderRowItem}
      />
```

Use render item like below code:

```
renderRowItem = (itemData) => {
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteAddress(itemData.item._id)}>
                    <Icon name="trash" style={{paddingLeft: 10,paddingRight:10}} size={20} color="red" />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete Flat List it would be more clear @Rahul

Comment: what are you performing in renderRowItem

Comment: I got it Thanks.

Comment: What is you this.keyExtractor?

Comment: _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could remove the desired item based on it's index.start with modifying the  flatList

```
<FlatList
          style={{ paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop: 10 }}
          data={this.state.imagesAddFile}
          keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
            <SelectedLayout
             onPress={(index) =>this.removeItemFromList(index)} 
             ImageName = {item.name}
            />
          )}
        />
```

you should wrap the component SelectedLayout inside a TouchableOpacity in order to implement onPress or whatever way you like it. if you could provide me with it's code I could show you.

now the removeItemFromList Implementation we're gonna use splice to remove it from imagesAddFile state.

```
removeItemFromList(index){
   let newimagesAddFile = this.state.imagesAddFile;
   newimagesAddFile.splice(index,1); //to remove a single item starting at index
   this.setState({imagesAddFile:newimagesAddFile})
}
```

Comment: How to remove in this function removeItemFromList ?

Comment: I submitted the first answer by mistake , I edited the complete one

Answer (score 1):

Since you code is not complete in your question, I assume that your `SelectedLayout` component might be having `TouchableOpacity` or something similar to handle tap (to select or remove image).
Basically what you want is to modify the datasource of your Flatlist (i.e this.state.imagesAddFile array) from `SelectedLayout` component.

Create a function in the component containing the flatlist that receives the image name (or image url depending on the structure of your image object) and that function should remove that image from your state (imagesAddFile). Now pass this function as a prop to your `SelectedLayout` and call this function from `SelectedLayout` component in onPress of your Touchable**** in `SelectedLayout`. You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) methods are they are very handy and well written.(You'd be using them a lot)

Your component might look something like this:

```
handleImageTap = (imageName) => {
   const { imagesAddFile } = this.state;
   this.setState({
      imagesAddFile: _.filter(imagesAddFile,imageObj => 
       imageObj.name !== imageName);
   })
}

render() {
  return(
   <FlatList
     style={{ paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop: 10 }}
     data={this.state.imagesAddFile}
     keyExtractor={(y, z) => z.toString()}
     renderItem={({ item }) => (
       <SelectedLayout
        ImageName = {item.name}
        handleImageTap = {this.handleImageTap}
       />
     )}
  />
  )
```

The line

```
_.filter(imagesAddFile,imageObj => imageObj.name !== imageName);
```

is nothing but just a JSX shorthand inside lodash filter method, which is taking imagesAddFile array, iterating over it and returning new array by removing the image object which is having the name equal to image name. Please refer the doc for better clarification.

Ideally you should be checking first whether the image exist in the array or not. Also i'd suggest not to play with image name, use something unique like id, or imageUrl